Accessing just a specific folder should redirect
I would like to be able to redirect users who visit a folder/directory in my nginx website I do not intend on people actually viewing. Example: if a client accessed a directory like https://example.com/_/ or https://example.com/_ they would be redirected to https://example.com/, but only if they haven't accessed anything inside that directory. For example, they shouldn't be redirected if they accessed a resource or another directory within that directory like https://example.com/_/image.jpg or https://example.com/_/fonts/.
I already have a plain ol HTML file which redirects but I find that crude and I want to replace it with a better solution. I tried setting up a location but I couldn't figure out how to make it not rewrite if its not just /_/ or /_. Here is the latest attempt (it didn't work):
location /_ {
    rewrite ^/_(?/)(!.*)$ https://example.com/ redirect;
}

I'm fairly new to Nginx and hosting websites so pardon me if I missed a very simple solution.

Not sure what the purpose of (!.*)$ is supposed to be. Why not just ^/_/?$ - request path starting with /_, plus an optional /, and then end of subject.

@CBroe
The proposed solution you gave, assuming you ment it like: location /_ { rewrite ^/_/?$ https://example.com/ redirect; } doesn't work for my case as now the files located in /_/ are inaccessable (404). Is it the way I wrote it missing something?

You want to redirect two URLs, /_ and /_/. But not anything else, like / and /_/foo, etc.
The location /_ rule matches any URL that begins with /_, so is not what you need.
The location = /_ rule matches a single URL.
So you could add two of these types of rule to redirect to https://example.com/.
For example:
location = /_ { return 301 /; }
location = /_/ { return 301 /; }

Note that Nginx will automatically add the scheme and hostname from the original request.

Thanks, this is exactly what i've been looking for.
